# How to upgrade my Icelandair ticket?

Tags: air-travel, luxury, upgrades, icelandair

I just purchased an Economy class ticket at Icelandair.com. I'd like to upgrade to [Saga Premium](https://www.icelandair.com/en-gb/support/on-board/classes-of-service/). What are my options for upgrading?

Comment: Are you looking to upgrade with cash or with miles (and if so which)? And any reason why you didn't do the upgrade at the time of the booking?

Comment: If you literally *just* purchased it, you may be able to just cancel your booking and start a new one with the appropriate travel class.  For instance, in the US, every airline is required to let you cancel within 24 hours of booking without penalty or fee.  I'm not sure if this applies when booking with a foreign carrier, though, and of course your local laws could be different, but it may be worth checking.

Comment: I booked the ticket a few weeks ago, sadly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Contact Icelandair

You can always [contact Icelandair](https://www.icelandair.com/en-gb/support/contact-us/) to have your ticket(s) upgraded to [Saga Premium](https://www.icelandair.com/en-gb/support/on-board/classes-of-service/).

## Bid for an upgrade

You can also bid for an upgrade to [Saga Premium](https://www.icelandair.com/en-gb/support/on-board/classes-of-service/) with Icelandair's [Class Up](https://www.icelandair.com/en-gb/support/pre-flight/class-up/).

On the Class Up page you can check your eligibility for Class Up, but you should also receive an e-mail regarding Class Up if you're eligible.

If you're more than one person travelling and you place a bid for e.g. `$80`, you'll be charged `$80 x 2 = $160`. If you want to split the booking and only upgrade some tickets you have to split it 10 days before departure.

You'll get a real Saga Premium ticket if you win, having lounge access, unlimited in-flight food and drinks and everything else that comes with Saga Premium.

---

### Subjective thoughts on *Class Up*

I've used Class Up many times and the calculation I usually do to decide whether or not to place a bid is usually the following:

- Do I require the [luxury](/questions/tagged/luxury) of first class this flight?
- Will [airport-security](/questions/tagged/airport-security) be crowded?
- Is there an Icelandair [lounge](/questions/tagged/lounge) at the departing [airport](/questions/tagged/airport)?
- Would I buy drinks and food at the airport and during flight?

After asking myself these questions I often do Class Up as it would cost the same as food and drinks - and I enjoy the lounges and the service.

Comment: Be aware that the _Class Up_ bidding might start at a much higher price. The last time I flew Icelandair, I figured I'd bid $50 just to see what happened, but I was told (for my itinerary) that bidding started at $280... per seat, per flight.